# Pull out 64 bit number from Hex using Java

Tags: java, numbers, hex, long-integer

I hope this makes sense. When I use a Hex editor and hover over a hex value you can see a 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit number (see screen shot for better idea)

[http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=2298915&l=e45630aead&id=1283154964 http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/189710_1899804496495_1283154964_2298915_5950535_n.jpg](http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/189710_1899804496495_1283154964_2298915_5950535_n.jpg)

Is there a way to pull that number out using Java, I need to pull the 64bit number out I don't know if this is possible?

If any one knows I would be very greatful!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do you have your hexadecimal value as String and want to use it in Java as a number? Or do you have a file from which you want to read it as bytes? Or do you want to connect with Java to your hex-editor?

Comment: Does the Hex editor obey the normal rules of copy-and-paste on your platform?  Can you make copy a number that you can then paste to the command prompt?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question.  You need to know something about the format of the number.  A 64-bit integer could be represented in multiple ways.  Is it little endian?  Big endian?  Unsigned?  Two's complement?

Comment: @rlibby in Java a 64 bit number is represented exactly one way - `long`.

Comment: @glowcoder, yes, but Simon hasn't said where this file came from.  Do we have any reason to think that this is, in fact, a Java long?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string of HEX that you want to convert to a 64 bit number, you can use

```
long asHex = Long.parseLong(theHexValue,16); // 16 denotes as hex
```

This will produce a SIGNED long value. If you're looking for `> 2^63`, you need to use BigInteger

```
BigInteger asHex = new BigInteger(theHexValue,16);
```